# Are common spaces of test functions "diffeomorphism-invariant"?

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, smooth-functions

Let $U,V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open subsets, and suppose there is a diffeomorphism $\phi : U \rightarrow V$.

Then, $\phi$ should induce a linear isomorphism between $C^\infty_c(U)$ and $C^\infty_c(V)$.

My 1st question is, does the bijection above also induce an isomorphism of topological vector spaces (TVSs)? Here we give these "test spaces of functions" the [canonical LF topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Canonical_LF_topology).

My 2nd question is, for what other common kinds of assignments of test spaces (e.g. Schwartz functions) does $\phi$ induce a TVS isomorphism?

Comment: One small point is that Schwartz functions (they and derivatives go to $0$ rapidly at infinity) are _not_ stable under diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb R^n$, because the "rapidly" has a _metric_ sense. The plain-ol' test functions just use compactness, which is a topological invariant, after all.